# Executing Android AsyncTask methods sequentially from Inside a 'For' loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Suppose I run an asyncTask from inside a 'For' loop(with 3 iterations) by calling 'AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR)'. 
At this point once I run the code, 'doInbackground()' runs for 3 times(3 times of for iteration) and then the 'onPostExecute()' runs again for 3 times.

So my doubt is if there is a way to execute the 'doInbackground()' and then 'onpostExecute()' for one iteration and then for next iteration in the same order.

Comment: You could call the next asynctask on the onPostExecute method of the previous right?

Comment: I don't think thats the right way to Handle my case because my async is called from inside a for loop

Comment: Whats the reason this question is down voted ? Is it unclear or what?

Answer (score 0):

use the AsyncTask's method get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) like that:

```
task.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This will make your main thread wait for the result of the AsyncTask at most 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to introduce delay. I want the async methods to execute sequentially

Comment: From AsyncTask docs:

Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
so if you are not >= HONEYCOMB, then maybe switch to use ExecutorService:

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();